# div box's in one line

Tags: html, css

hy guys. i have again a lil problem.

Im trying to make a box with some div in a signle line.

the problem is that if i start a new div, its at the top of the one which is before him and not next to him.

i tryed it with float left or border-sizing and display table cell . it all didnt work. http://www.awesom-media.de/umgebung/index.html

its the one with the greenbackground.

in this part should be 4 icon divs . two are already there. and in the red box would come some content wich get showed if the visitors are clicking on each icon.

but the problem is like i said that i cant get the two icons (magicstick and the star ) in one line .

Comment: Could you post a little code or make a JSFIDDLE so we can have a better idea of what we are working with. Your problem is very easy to fix ;)

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS and create a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J4QWq/

like i said. in the red box are coming some other coment which i didnt start yet. and in the greenone are 2 more coming .

ah and by the way when im askin. as u can see on the site there are some icons which has a nice hover effekt. could ja tell me how i will get this one on the new box / icons. its a template which im using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/GAA9e/

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the css property  each div (magic and wand) to float:left; and the webicons div to clear:left;

```
#magic { float:left; }
#wand { float:left; }
#webicons  { clear: left; height:110px; }
```

**DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/J4QWq/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I added `float: left;` to each of your icons and added `height: 100%;` in `.webicons` like so :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J4QWq/1/)

Hope this helps!